# Openshift 4.19 (Kubernetes 1.19) Tomcat spring app overwrite deployed file with config map entry clears complete deployment directory

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, openshift, logback, configmap

I have a Spring Boot app deployed under a Tomcat server inside a POD with Openshift 4.19 (which uses Kubernetes 1.19). My goal is to externalize the logback configuration to a configmap, so that I can change the loglevel as needed in production without restarting the pods.

I used the following configuration:

**ConfigMap**

```
    kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: logback-configmap
[..]
data:
  logback: |
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="60 seconds">
[...]
```

**Deployment Config**

```
[...]
spec:
      volumes:
        - name: logback-configmap-volume
          configMap:
            name: logback-configmap
            items:
              - key: logback
                path: logback.xml
            defaultMode: 420
[..]
         volumeMounts:
            - name: logback-configmap-volume
              mountPath: /deployments/zfaRouter/WEB-INF/classes/logback.xml
              subPath: logback.xml
[..]
```

The problem is, that the above config clears the complete directory structure under /deployments/zfaRouter/WEB-INF/classes/:

```
sh-4.4$ ls -la /deployments/zfaRouter/WEB-INF/classes/
total 4
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root         25 May  4 16:35 .
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root         21 May  4 16:35 ..
-rw-r--r--. 1 root 1015170000 1084 May  4 16:35 logback.xml
```

I tried every possible combination (eg. without subPath element, without the filename in the mountPath, without the items element in the volumes section) without any luck. From what a read here and in the official Kubernetes docs, it should work like the configuration above.

Any ideas on this problem?

Comment: It would be surprising a volumeMounts with a subPath/mountPath identifying a specific file would overwrite the parent directory content. Are you sure there isn't some emptyDir, or something else, that would be mounted on `/deployments/zfaRouter/WEB-INF/classes/` ?

Comment: Maybe a previous volumeMount? When you apply an object, updating one that already existed, beware you're not necessarily replacing the previous definition, rather "patching", "merging" two objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The directory that is used as mount point shadows all other content, therefore it appears like overwriting what you expect to be there. Even if you want to 'just' have a single file mounted, a mount point must exist.

For your specific scenario you could either mount to a different directory, like `/config` and add it to the classpath, or you can use a subdirectory like `/deployments/zfaRouter/WEB-INF/classes/config` and add that to the classpath.

If you don't want to change the classpath you could mount the config file to, f.e. `/config` and change your application start script to copy it to a fitting location, for example to the tomcat shared lib folder that is picked up by the tomcat classloader.

Comment: That was exactly the solution: I changed the mount point to an external directoy /config and added "-Dlogging.conf=/config/logback.xml" to the JAVA_OPTS_APPEND environment of the deployment config. Thanks a lot.